# How to get product collection with both in stock and out of stock products in Magento 2.1

Tags: magento-2.1, product-collection, out-of-stock

I'm using below code to get the product collection

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Product;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection;

class Manage extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template {


        public function __construct(
                Template\Context $context
                , Collection $productFactory
                , array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->productFactory = $productFactory;
        parent::__construct ( $context, $data );
    }

    public function getFilterProducts() {

        $product = $this->productFactory->addAttributeToSelect ( '*' );

        $product->addAttributeToFilter ( 'visibility', array (
                'eq' => \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH 
        ) );
        $product->addAttributeToSort ( 'entity_id', 'DESC' );

        return $product;
    }

}
```

But above code gives me only ***in stock*** products, how do I include ***out of stock*** products in this collection?

Answer (score 4):

Use below code

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$productCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory');
$collection = $productCollection->create();
$collection->setFlag('has_stock_status_filter', true);
$collection = $collection
->joinField('qty',
        'cataloginventory_stock_item',
        'qty',
        'product_id=entity_id',
        '{{table}}.stock_id=1',
        'left'
    )->joinTable('cataloginventory_stock_item', 'product_id=entity_id', array('stock_status' => 'is_in_stock'))
    ->addAttributeToSelect('stock_status')
    ->load();
```

Or replace your function with below

```
public function getFilterProducts() {

        $product = $this->productFactory->create();
        $product->addAttributeToSelect ( '*' )->setFlag('has_stock_status_filter', true);
        $product = $product
        ->joinField('qty',
                'cataloginventory_stock_item',
                'qty',
                'product_id=entity_id',
                '{{table}}.stock_id=1',
                'left'
            )->joinTable('cataloginventory_stock_item', 'product_id=entity_id', array('stock_status' => 'is_in_stock'))
            ->addAttributeToSelect('stock_status')
            ->addAttributeToSort ( 'entity_id', 'DESC' )
            ->addAttributeToFilter('status',\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_ENABLED)
            ->load();
        return $product;
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

By default magento filters only in stock products in collection. We have to set the in stock filter as false.

```
$productCollection = $_objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory');

$collection = $productCollection->create()->setFlag('has_stock_status_filter', false)->load();
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add below line before return $product statement.

```
$product->setFlag('has_stock_status_filter', true);
```

Then return $product;

It would work !!!