# Out of stock products: why do they appear in Collection::getAllIds and not in Collection::getItems

Tags: magento2, collection, products, product-collection, stock

Im trying to get all products in a collection: out of stock and products in stock.
So what I did is:

```
/** @var $collection \Magentp\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection */
$collection = $this->productCollectionFactory->create();
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH);
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('status', \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_ENABLED);
$collection->sePageSize(3);
$collection->setCurPage(1);
```

Now, when I use a `foreach()` loop with `$collection->getItems()` as the array expression, it just shows the products that have stock, but when I use the `$collection->getAllIds()` instead, it includes the products out of stock.

Can anyone explain why?

Comment: By default magento filters only in stock products in collection. We have to set the in stock filter as false and follow code this --- https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/261620/85907

Comment: Awesome, that helped me to understand it. You can add it to the answers section so I can mark it as correct :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default magento filters only in stock products in collection. We have to set the in stock filter as false.

```
$productCollection = $_objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory');

$collection = $productCollection->create()->setFlag('has_stock_status_filter', false)->load();
```

And information this link ---

**[How to get product collection with both in stock and out of stock products in Magento 2.1](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/241709/how-to-get-product-collection-with-both-in-stock-and-out-of-stock-products-in-ma/261620#261620)**

Hope this help you

Thanks ...